# When Convergence Implies Integrable Stopping Times

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stopping-times

Let $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a stochastic process such that:
$$
n^{-1}X_n \to k < 0 \quad a.s.
$$
I want to prove that if $X_0=0$, and $\tau=\inf\{ n\geq 1: X_n\leq 0 \} $, then $\mathbb{E}[\tau]<\infty$, or at least, under what conditions this is true. My instinct is that, if the Markov chain is time homogeneous (and perhaps under weaker conditions) then it is true, but I'm not sure where to begin with proving it.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned time-homogeneous Markov chains. Here's one idea to explore: you can construct such a chain which moves up the non-negative integers one step at a time, before eventually jumping to state $-1$, with literally *any* distribution of $\tau $ that you desire!

If you want $P(\tau=m)=\alpha_m$ for $m\geq 1$, then for each such $m$ define the transition probabilities $p_{m-1,-1}=\alpha_m/(\sum_{i=m}^\infty \alpha_i)$, and $p_{m-1,m}=1-p_{m-1,-1}$.

Then you can separately arrange the behaviour of your chain on the negative integers so that starting from $-1$, it always stays negative and satisfies your desired condition that  $n^{-1} X_n \to k$ as $n\to\infty$ with probability $1$. (If that convergence holds for the path started at $-1$, then it doesn't matter what extra finite portion you add on the beginning, it will still hold.)

Comment: That's a neat construction James, thanks. I think my comment about time-homogeneity really should be about time and space homogeneity because while this is indeed time-homogeneous by definition, if $X_0=0$ is fixed, then the size of jumps the process can take is time dependent (ie. if $X_0=0$, then for $X_n>0$, the maximum jump of $X$ is at most the $n$) so it is in some weaker sense dependent on time. I think perhaps some condition like $P(X(t+s)\in S+a | X(t)=a)$ is independent of $t, a$ might give the desired result, without $X$ even necessarily being a Markov process.